# Install Recaptcha plugin into Jekyll-generated site

Tags: ruby, recaptcha, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to install the Ambethia recaptcha plugin into a jekyll-generated site that uses Liquid templating to generate forms. Since the site is not running on Rails, I'm having a bit of difficulty translating what needs to be put where.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible b/c recaptcha requires server-side code, and `jekyll`-generated sites are completely static. (javascript not counts here)

Comment: That's what I feared. Thanks, @zed_0xff.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to add recaptcha to "filter out" spam comments, I suggest you give [disqus](http://disqus.com/dashboard/) a try.

I believe there are plugins to integrate it with jekyll (for example, [octopress](http://octopress.org/) comes with disqus integration) but the [code to include them in your site is really simple](http://docs.disqus.com/developers/universal/).

Comment: Thanks. Specifically, I'm trying to prevent spam from coming through web form sign-ups for my site, but disqus might do the trick. FWIW, a friend had suggested using a simple Sinatra app as an intermediary between the form and the Marketo CRM we use, which led me to [this post](http://vitobotta.com/sinatra-contact-form-jekyll/) by Vito Botta.